# Get all Deployments referencing given ConfigMap by the ConfigMap's name

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Suppose I have a `ConfigMap`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: london-tz-config
data:
  SERVER_TIMEZONE: "Europe/London"
```

I also have about 50 distinct Deployments. Let's say that 20 of them use the `london-tz-config` ConfigMap to set their environments, like this

```
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo-app-container
          image: ealen/echo-server:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: SERVER_TIMEZONE
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: london-tz-config    # Reference our ConfigMap here
                  key: SERVER_TIMEZONE
```

I don't know which Deployments use which ConfigMaps at any given time without manually inspecting the cluster.

Is there a way to ask Kubernetes to show me all Deployments that contain references to a given ConfigMap by its `metadata.name` attribute?

Either `kubectl` or the Kubernetes API would be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `kubectl get -o json` and parse the output using [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to iterate over the deployments, matching any desired `configMapKeyRef.name` and returning a `uniq` list of deployments.

This should work:

```
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces -o json | jq -r '.items | map(select(.spec.template.spec.containers[]?.env[]?.valueFrom.configMapKeyRef.name == "london-tz-config" ) | .metadata.name) | .[]' | uniq
```